# Line Up Bootstrap Featurette Text With The Image Above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is this: I have one Bootstrap Featurette below another. Both have an image and both have both a header and a paragraph (As you can see [here](http://jawa-jawaeyes.c9.io)). My problem is that the text on the lower Featurette does not line up horizontally with the image on the higher featurette, and I cannot seem to fix it or find instructions on how to fix it, so I came here for some help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example Shop</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/media-shuffle.png" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- FontAwesome Integration -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/animate.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" async></script>
    <style>body {opacity: 0}</style><noscript><style>body {opacity: 1}</style></noscript>
  </head>
    <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'msemibold';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url('fonts/MYRIADPRO-SEMIBOLD.woff') format('woff');
      }
      @font-face {
          font-family: 'mpro';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: normal;
          src: url('fonts/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'bebas';
        src: url('fonts/bebas/BebasNeueRegular.otf');
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'bebasbold';
        src: url('fonts/bebas/BebasNeueBold.otf');
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'sspro';
        src: url('fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf');
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'ssprobold';
        src: url('fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.otf') format('opentype'), url('fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
      }

      .jumbotron {
        background-image: url('images/background.png');
        margin-top: 0;
        font-family: 'bebasbold';
        color: black;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
      }

      .firstheader {
        text-align: left;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #585c65;
      }

      a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

      body {
        background-image: url('images/dark-background.png');
      }

      .textbody {
        color: white;
        font-family: arial;
        padding-left: 1%;
      }

      .gamer {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'bebasbold';
        border-color: #585c65;
      }

      .stream {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'bebasbold';
      }

      .featurette-divider {
        border-color: #585c65;
        margin: 80px;
      }

      .lead {
        font-family: 'mpro';
      }

      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .container-fluid {
          overflow-x: hidden;
          white-space: nowrap;
          font-family: 'bebasbold';
        }
      }
    </style>

      <body>
        <div class="jumbotron container-fluid navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="firstheader">The Digital Card Shop <small>. <a href="#">About Us</a> | . <a href="#">Contact Us</a> | . <a href="#">Sell Your Account</a></small></h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <container class="gamer">
            <div class="row featurette">
              <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-6">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Star Wars Card Trader <span class="text-muted">We Buy & Sell Cards.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Star Wars is awesome. For that reason, <br> it remains one of the most popular subjects for trading cards;<br> Both physically and digitally.
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
                <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/swct.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
              </div>
            </div>

          </container>

          <hr class="featurette-divider">

          <div class="container-fluid">
          <container class="gamer">
            <div class="row featurette">
              <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-2">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Topps KICK 16 <span class="text-muted">We Buy & Sell Cards.</span></h2>
                <p1 class="lead">Football (It isn't called soccer) is awesome. For that reason, <br> It remains one of the most popular subjects for trading cards;<br> Both physically and digitally. (Please add Derby County cards Topps)
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-1">
                <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="images/kick.png" height="200px" width="200px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
              </div>
            </div>
            <br></br><br></br><br>
          </container>





      </body>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your html here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how your code should look https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/36/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" height="200px" width="200px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">Topps KICK 16 <span class="text-muted">We Buy & Sell Cards.</span></h2>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolorem totam aliquam dolores amet repellendus aperiam, eligendi illum voluptatem vero.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">Topps KICK 16 <span class="text-muted">We Buy & Sell Cards.</span></h2>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi dolorem totam aliquam dolores amet repellendus aperiam, eligendi illum voluptatem vero.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" height="200px" width="200px" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! In the spirit of learning, what was I doing wrong or what was I doing to make the featurettes misalign?

Comment: I don't think you can set `col-md-5` and `col-sm-7`. It has to be `col-md-5` and `col-md-7` or like this `col-sm-5` and `col-sm-7`, also you were complicating things with push and pull columns for no reason. Also i don't think `p1` and `container` are real `HTML` elements but i might be wrong here.